# Why did this question not get any votes in the last 6 months despite getting 49 views and 4 upvotes on a comment?

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, specific-question

As with the following two threads:

- [Why did this question not get any votes in the last 5.5 months despite getting 61 views and comments from at least 3 different people?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/366/5)
- [Why is nobody voting on this question, but so many people are voting on the comments?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/424/5)

I'm seeking the community's opinion about why [this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10667/5) is not getting any votes, despite at least 4 people other than the OP and me seeing the question:

[image]

I can see reasons why this question wouldn't be considered ***perfect*** by MMSE standards, but it's [anomalous for voting on a question by this user to be so much neglected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsH6x.png). **I'm curious what it is about the question that caused none of you to vote on it?**